# How to use `GET` and `POST` parameters inside Static Assets in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get, static-files

When using PHP to render pages that make use of the request parameters of `GET` and `POST`, we can do something similar to:

```
<p>Hello, <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?>!</p>
```

And when we request the file like: `/?name=Mike`, we get the following output:

```
<p>Hello, Mike!</p>
```

Using Node JS and Express JS, I serve static files using the following universal code:

```
app.get('/user/:name', function(req, res) {
    res.render('user.html', {
        UserName: req.params.name
    });
});
```

Here, in the `user.html`, I would like to use something like:

```
<p>Hello, <? document.write(UserName); ?>!</p>
<p>Hello, <? document.write(req.params.name); ?>!</p>
```

Something, that switches into the server side and then gets the params and displays here. Is there any way to do it using the static files, where `user.html` is a static file?

Comment: you can use `ejs` or `pug` or other templating engine to solve the problem.

Comment: @MukeshSharma We are using mustache on the server side and handlebars on client and they are conflicting. Is there any way to do this all with handlebars?

Comment: Yes, you can use handlebars too. Follow the documentation.

Comment: MongoDB is also an option, and it works relatively seamless.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can do it by using RegularExperssion in Query String

the request URL would be like this  **"http://servername/Profile?Name=Amir"**

```
   app.get(new RegExp("Profile(\\.(?:htm|html))?(\\?.*)?$"), function (req, res) {


        var queryData = url.parse(req.url, true).query;

        var Name = queryData.Name;
        console.log(Name)

           res.render(__dirname + "/Pages/AppView.ejs", {
                username: Name ,
            })
        })
```

in ejs template would be like :

```
<h1> Welcome , <%= username %> </h1>
```